# Filtering Excel sheet using power automate desktop recorder

Tags: excel, power-automate-desktop

How to filter columns in Excel using power automate desktop recorder

New to power automate and not much of a programmer, so I thought to use the recording feature on power automate desktop to document how I complete my Excel reports. A crucial step in completing said reports is filtering the headings. My program keeps getting stuck on the action of me clicking on the filter button after clicking the Sort & Filter dropdown. It reads...

Select menu option in Window

MenuItem: Sort & Filter

Select menu option in Window

MenuItem: Sort & Filter -> Filter

The second step above is getting the error "Failed to select option (option wasn't found)"

I've tried to key in control + shift + L, I've tried to have a UI action, and I get the same error every time.